# How does NSDate seem to know it's TimeZone?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm somewhat confused about how these two NSDate objects seem to know which timezone they are in. I was under the impression that an NSDate object only stored a point in time and no information about the timezone.

I'm creating and logging two dates like this:

```
NSString* timeString = @"6:04 PM";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
NSDate *time = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeString];

NSDateFormatter *currentFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[currentFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSLog(@"%@", [currentFormatter stringFromDate:time]);
NSLog(@"%@", [currentFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

This produces the output:

```
18:04:00 GMT
11:12:36 BST
```

How does it know that the first date is GMT and the second is BST?

(It's British Summer Time here. Your mileage may vary in that respect)

Comment: You are sure that this is the code that give us this output? I got an output with the same timezone with your code.

Comment: Yes, running on iOS 9 on an iPhone 6s with my region set at United Kingdom, Time Zone set to London and 24-Hour Time on. Xcode 7.0.1.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm using iOS 9.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, `NSDate` doesn't have a time zone. Your results don't contradict that, because you're not printing the dates-- you're printing a subset of the date information produced by passing them through a date formatter. Your `currentFormatter` only returns time of day information, not date information. If you add this line:

```
[currentFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
```

Then the results will look something like:

```
January 1, 2000 at 6:04:00 PM MST
September 30, 2015 at 11:14:39 AM MDT
```

In other words, they show up with different time zones because they're on different dates, and the time zone reflects what's in effect on that date. In my case it's currently `MDT` but on Jan 1 2000 it would have been `MST`.